# Manga where the main character meets three (or four) sisters who steal the life force of men

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga is about a guy going to this town with only girls, I think, and he meets these sisters. I think there are 3 of them, or four, and what's different about them is that they look like normal humans, but they steal the life force of men and that's why there are no men in that village or town.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: Black and white

Comment: Did he defeat them in combat and they basically switch allegiances, and then set a trap for their former master/employer/demon king/whatever on behalf of the MC? Except now that I type that out I can't remember the title of it anyway.

Comment: No but I know what manga you were talking about

Comment: Do you remember the name of it, by chance? If so, it'd be helpful to edit it into the question as something you're certain it's not. Regardless, are you able to remember any other details about this story, such as what happens before or after the MC goes to this town? And since this is likely about succubi, was this a pornographic story or more like an action story?

Comment: The manga you were talking was next life I'm pretty sure. And after the mc went into town he was attacked in his sleep and was freaked out then I think and ran away and then the sister explained about what they are and why no men come to this town or village